# Force focus to a certain index in ListView

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-ui-listview

I create a list and depending on the input given by the user I want it to focus on a certain element in the list.

```
<ListView for="(item, index) in timeTable" @itemTap="onItemTap">
    <v-template>
            <FlexboxLayout class="travelDetails" :ref="index">
            </FlexboxLayout>
    </v-template>
</ListView>

created: function(){
     this.$refs[this.indexIWantToFocusOn].nativeView.focus()
}
```

But the problem is the reference of that element isn't rendered yet.

So is there a way to force that index should start at other value than 0?

Or Is there another way around?

Comment: By focus you mean that you want your list to start at the desired index?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try scrolling to the desired index after the ListView is loaded through `scrollToIndex`. Check the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_list_view_.listview#scrolltoindex).

```xml
<ListView for="item in timeTable" @itemTap="onItemTap"
    ref="myList" @loaded="onLoaded">
    <v-template>
        <FlexboxLayout class="travelDetails">
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </v-template>
</ListView>
```

```js
onLoaded() {
    this.$refs.myList.nativeView.scrollToIndex(this.indexIWantToFocusOn);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works. But one issue I need to put the `onLoaded` function in `setTimeOut` because my `ListView` isn't generated but he executes the `onLoaded` function already.